# Issue in publishing whole website after upgrading from 7.1 to 7.2(release)

Tags: sitecore, upgrade, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore7.1

We have upgraded sitecore version from 7.1 to 7.2 and we are on the last step where we need to publish whole website. When we tried to publish whole website, we are got following error:

```
Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.OverridePublishContext, Sitecore.Kernel (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(String type, XmlNode processorNode)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishPipeline.Run(PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher.Publish()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(`enter code here`Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

Comment: I've never seen `OverridePublishContext` class in original Sitecore.Kernel dll. Which version you upgrade from? Can you check your config files, which of them added it to the publish pipeline? Can you check original configs from before upgrade if it was the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When having the issue Could not resolve type name, this means that your dlls are not up to date or your config files.

Please check your dlls against dlls from a fresh installation of Sitecore 7.2. Also check the config files. Moreover, check that you dlls have been compiled against the Sitecore 7.2 dlls.

Thanks